# Clicking an object visually doesn't select it in IB Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode7.3

Is there a way to visually outline the selected object in IB?. I noticed that when an object is selected in IB, the object shows selected in the Document Outline but it doesn't in the Design view:

[image]

However, if the object happens to have constraints, then there's a frame that gets drawn around it or at least the constraints are shown (depending on the Editor settings you have selected), but there are clues which object is selected in the Design view:

[image]

I know that if you click twice on the object, then a deep selection is made, but then you can't move the object; you can just act upon it to other actions but not moving it:

[image]

Comment: Does any of the options in Editor/Canvas fulfill your needs. There's several options there that will highlight the item in one way or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have Resize Knobs disabled. These are normally on by default and would outline the selected view.

To enable them click Editor -> Canvas -> Show Resize Knobs in Xcode.

[image: Image showing the menu item]